# How to make Search Suggestions work Globally for Napili Community

Tags: community, global-search

I am using Salesforce Communities with Napili Template and have requirement to configure Header search component (Search Publisher) to work globally ALWAYS even if I am any topic detail page suggestion box should return exact same result as it returns when we are on Home page.

We have configurable property named as "Topic ID" for Search Result page (will appear after clicking on Search button) but did not find it for Header Search Publisher component which shows suggestions before clicking on Search Button.

Is there something I can do by configuration ?

Comment: Here is an Idea for the same, If you are also facing same issue, please vote for it 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CLhjQAG

Answer (score 1):

No: this is definitely something we'd like to see made available. **Right now, the search suggestions only work for the active Topic**